# Change Dataset to Support Effective Identity

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I attempted an embed with the App Owns Data sample and am unable to implement RLS because "This checkbox is disabled because the current report does not support providing effective user name." So how do I convert my dataset, which is a SQL database on Azure, to support effective identity? Interestingly, I am able to view as different roles from within Power BI Desktop.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing that message: "This checkbox is disabled because the current report does not support providing effective user name." Are you using Direct Query or an imported data model?

Comment: Imported SQL database on Azure. It's in the App Owns Data sample, on the Report Embed page. https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples